# Angle between vectors 360 degrees

Tags: c#, qvector3d

I want to calculate the angle between a vector3d and other vectors3d in 360 degrees

I have tried this with vector3d.AngleBetween but this gives results in 180 degrees

```
//Create a new 3d vector from average points
Vector3D vector1 = new Vector3D(averageX, averageY, 0);

//Create reference vector
Vector3D vector2 = new Vector3D(averageX-100, averageY, 0);
Vector3D vectorResult1 = new Vector3D();

vectorResult1 = vector2 - vector1;                       

//Other vector to all points in layer
foreach (XYZ d1 in coord)
 {                                
   Vector3D vector3 = new Vector3D(d1.X, d1.Y, d1.Z);
   Vector3D vectorResult2 = new Vector3D();

   vectorResult2 = vector3-vector1;

   //Define a rotation

   double angleBetween = Vector3D.AngleBetween(vectorResult2, vectorResult1);
 }
```

Comment: What is the *actual value* and *desired* one?

Comment: Why 360? Unless you specify a rotation direction, there's no difference. A 90° clockwise angle is the same as a 270° counterclockwise angle.

Comment: I need every angle between the vectors so i can sort them. With the results i want to sort points Clockwise

Answer (score 0):

I you have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.anglebetween?view=netframework-4.7.2) you'll see that *Signed angles do not extend into 3-D space, so an angle between 0 and 180 degrees is returned.*. It's in the Remarks.